# Android: Pass onClick event from Child View to Parent View under certain conditions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`. The `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` has `setOnClickListener` set and process the click events. However, under certain conditions, I want to pass that event to the parent view so that a difference action can be taken.

I am using the below code and it is working but I am not sure if it is the right way. I am few questions:

1. How will the parent know the coordinates of touch event? I am calling `performClick` which doesn't take any arguments.
2. Is it right way to handle such use case? Is there any better way to  achieve the same?

```
class ViewHolder(
        itemView: View
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(ratingColumnDataModel: RatingColumnDataModel, ratingClickListener: IRatingClickListener) {
        val childView = canvasCellRatingBinding.ratingCellLinearLayout.getChildAt(childIndex)
        if (childView is ImageView) {
            childView.tag = (starIndex + 1).toString()
            childView.setOnClickListener {
                val pair = getRowAndColumnIndex()
                if ((pair?.second ?: -1) == 0) {
                    // Let parent handle the click
                    (it.parent as View).performClick()
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                // Handle click event in child
                println("Child handling click event")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way with `ClickListener` in case you need Touch coordinates then you have add `TouchListener` on View . Also you need validate the Click Event yourself for this case ..

Comment: I don't need coordinates. I didn't get the part `Also you need validate the Click Event yourself for this case `.